# how to create dots in pagination or breadcrumb if they are too much in number

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I want to create dots in breadcrumb if they exceeds some specific limit of numbers.  I added script, to create breadcrumb but it's not working.

I am stuck where i have to add dots so that when bread crumb item exceeds it hides and create dots

```js
function getBreadCrumb() {
  if (window.ActiveTab != 'local') {
    $('#fr-h-r-3 .breadcrumb.fr-breadcrumb').html('');
    return false
  }

  /*alert(window.ActiveTab);
  if(window.ActiveTab == 'fb'){
    $('#fr-h-r-3 .breadcrumb.fr-breadcrumb').html('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$(document).trigger(\'ImageManager.LoadBreadCrumbFolder\',[this]);" data-name="Facebook-Images" data-hist="Facebook-Images/" data-path="'+b.opts.userFolderDefaultPath+'Facebook-Images">Facebook-Images</a></li>');
    return false;
  }else if(window.ActiveTab == 'ig'){
    $('#fr-h-r-3 .breadcrumb.fr-breadcrumb').html('<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$(document).trigger(\'ImageManager.LoadBreadCrumbFolder\',[this]);" data-name="Instagram-Images" data-hist="Instagram-Images/" data-path="'+b.opts.userFolderDefaultPath+'Instagram-Images">Instagram-Images</a></li>');
    return false
  }*/

  var currentPath = b.opts.userFolderDefaultPath;
  if (b.opts.imageManagerFolders.length > 0) {
    currentPath = b.opts.userFolderDefaultPath + b.opts.imageManagerFolders.join('/') + '/';
  }
  var sArray = currentPath.split('/');
  var fArray = currentPath.split('/');

  fArray.pop();
  fArray.shift();
  sArray.shift();
  sArray.shift();
  sArray.shift();
  sArray.pop();
  var html = '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="$(document).trigger(\'ImageManager.LoadBreadCrumbFolder\',[this]);" data-name="#home" data-hist="" data-path="/' + fArray[0] + '/' + fArray[1] + '/"><span class="fa fa-home"></span></a></li>';

  /*console.log('sArray: '+sArray);
  console.log('fArray: '+fArray);*/

  function getPath(i) {
    var hisPath = '';
    for (var j = 2; j < (i + 3); j++) {
      if (fArray[j] != 'undefined') {
        hisPath += fArray[j] + '/';
      }
    }
    return hisPath;
  }

  if (sArray.length > 6) {
    as = 4;
    al = (sArray.length - 3)
  }
  sts = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < sArray.length; i++) {

    if ((i + 1) != sArray.length) {
      if (typeof as != 'undefined' && i == as) {
        sts = true;
      }
      if (typeof al != 'undefined' && i == al) sts = false;
      if (sts == false) {
        html += '<li><a onClick="$(document).trigger(\'ImageManager.LoadBreadCrumbFolder\',[this]);" href="javascript:void(0);" data-name="' + sArray[i] + '" data-hist="' + getPath(i) + '" data-path="/' + fArray[0] + '/' + fArray[1] + '/' + getPath(i) + '">' + sArray[i] + '</a></li>';
      }
    } else {
      html += '<li class="active">' + sArray[i] + '</li>';
    }

    //html += '<li class="active">'+sArray[i]+'</li>';
  }
  $('#fr-h-r-3 .breadcrumb.fr-breadcrumb').html(html);
}
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and add HTML so we have a [mcve] - also please do not tell us how urgent it is. If the question is clear and effort has been shown, you will likely get an answer very quickly. Since there is no [mcve] it will take longer and the question may be voted down and closed

Comment: Use jquery paggination its much better http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: Thanks guys i solved the problem and i posted the answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your efforts, i was working on this, i solved this by only adding this code into function.

```
if(typeof as != 'undefined' && i==as) { sts = true; html += '<li>...</li>'; }
```

where the line is

```
if (typeof as != 'undefined' && i == as) {
    sts = true;
  }
```

this script is generating a pagination you can see in script. and the final output is this.
simple pagination without dots.

```
checkttttNew-Folder-1New-Folder-1New-Folder-1
```

when exceeds 6 li then it creates dots. like this.

```
checkttttNew-Folder-1New-Folder-1...New-Folder-1htesttes2
```

Comment: the codes are may not broad specific to my project. but thank you #stackoverflow community for continues help. :)